# Can I use the value of a request parameter in an interceptor param declaration in struts.xml?

Tags: java, parameters, struts2, interceptor

I'm using Struts 2.3.

I have an interceptor with a parameter (note: code slightly simplified to remove some casts):

```
private String parameterName = null;
private String parameterValueSuffixParameter = null;
// getter and setter.

// in my doIntercept(), get the view.suffix Integer parameter from the page;
parameterName.concat(context.getParameters().get(parameterValueSuffixParameter)[0]);
```

This parameter is defined on the struts.xml action definition:

```
<action name="actionName" method="methodName" class="com.example.myAction>
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack">
        <param name="interceptor.parameterName">parameterValue</param>
        <param name="interceptor.parameterValueSuffixParameter">view.suffix</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <result name="success">/jsp/result.jsp</result>
</action>
```

and on the page:

```
<s:hidden name="view.suffix" value="%{view.suffx}" />
```

Now, what I want to do is get rid of the extra parameter in my struts.xml and the parameter.concat line by directly using the value of the suffix in my interceptor param. Is this possible?

I already tried `parameterValue${view.suffix}`, but that didn't work, parameterName was literally set to that as a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking some issues on the struts Jira, I found that this functionality has been implemented in Struts 2.5.9 using Lazy Parameters, but is not available in Struts 2.3, which I am using. Since updating Struts2 is not feasible at my current stage of development, I will have to make do with my workaround.